# Swift Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x161174110> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: arrays, swift, enumeration

I understand that I can't add or remove an element from an array while it's being enumerated, but...I'm not! I think I have narrowed down where the crash happens but it doesn't make any sense to me.

```
func sendToCloud() {
   for quoteNumber in newQuotes {
      let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Quotes")
      let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "quoteNumber == %@", quoteNumber)
      fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
      fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
      do {
          //The next two lines is where the crash happens...
          quotes = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
          let currentQuote = quotes.first as! Quotes
          //-------------------------------------------
          prepRecordForCoreData(obj: currentQuote, recordName: currentQuote.ckrecordname!, recordType: "Quotes")
          repRecordForCoreData(obj: currentQuote.customer!, recordName: currentQuote.ckrefcustomer!, recordType: "Customers")
      } catch let error as NSError {
          print("ERROR SAVING TO CLOUD", error)
      }
   }
   //clear array
   newQuotes = []

   coreData.saveContext { (success) -> Void in
      if success {
         AppData.uploadRecords()
      }
   }
}
```

Just in case...

```
func prepRecordForCoreData(obj: SignatureManagedObject, recordName: String, recordType: String) {
   let zone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: Contstants.Strings.zoneName)
   let id = CKRecord.ID(recordName: recordName, zoneID: zone.zoneID)
   let record = CKRecord(recordType: recordType, recordID: id)
   let coder = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)
   record.encodeSystemFields(with: coder)
   let metadata = coder.encodedData
   obj.ckmetadata = metadata
   obj.ckrecordname = recordName
   obj.ckupload = true
}
```

Comment: Where is `quotes` declared? Why isn't that a local variable?

Comment: I suspect that you're accessing `quotes` on multiple queues (and possibly not the queue that `context` is assigned to).  I would explore that possibility.